# R: Capitalizing everything after a certain character

Tags: regex, r, capitalization

I would like to capitalize everything in a character vector that comes after the first `_`. For example the following vector:

```
x <- c("NYC_23df", "BOS_3_rb", "mgh_3_3_f")
```

Should come out like this:

```
"NYC_23DF" "BOS_3_RB" "mgh_3_3_F"
```

I have been trying to play with [regular expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html), but am not able to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `gsub("(\\_*)", "", x)` picks `_`, but doesn't pick the rest of the string. There are good examples on capitalization in the help sheet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You were very close:

```
gsub("(_.*)","\\U\\1",x,perl=TRUE)
```

seems to work.  You just needed to use `_.*` (underscore followed by zero or more other characters) rather than `_*` (zero or more underscores) ...

To take this apart a bit more:

- `_.*` gives a regular expression pattern that matches an underscore `_` followed by any number (including 0) of additional characters; `.` denotes "any character" and `*` denotes "zero or more repeats of the previous element"
- surrounding this regular expression with parentheses `()` denotes that it is a pattern we want to store
- `\\1` in the replacement string says "insert the contents of the first matched pattern", i.e. whatever matched `_.*`
- `\\U`, in conjunction with `perl=TRUE`, says "put what follows in upper case" (uppercasing `_` has no effect; if we wanted to capitalize everything after (for example) a lower-case g, we would need to exclude the g from the stored pattern and include it in the replacement pattern: `gsub("g(.*)","g\\U\\1",x,perl=TRUE)`)

For more details, search for "replacement" and "capitalizing" in `?gsub` (and `?regexp` for general information about regular expressions)

Comment: +1 for the `"\\U\\1"`. Never seen that kind of regex before in R. Could you explain what this does in particular and/or where to look it up? I assume `"\\U"` handles the uppercase, but I don't really get the `"\\1"`. Thanks!

Comment: The `\\1` is a back-reference to the first matched pattern.  It's all in the examples for `?gsub`, which is where I looked ...

Comment: As so often when working with R: the answer is so simple, only if you know what you're doing =D. Thanks Ben Bolker!

Comment: I love regex solutions like this; simple. +1  I myself have benefited from regex solutions like this, especially, when the poster adds info about what each piece is doing.  Ben if it's  not too much trouble could you add a slight bit of explanation about what each piece is doing for future thread searchers?

Answer (score 14):

`gsubfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a function.  Here we match _ and everything afterwards feeding the match through `toupper` :

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("_.*", toupper, x)
## [1] "NYC_23DF"  "BOS_3_RB"  "mgh_3_3_F"
```

Note that this approach involves a particularly simple regular expression.

Comment: I can't believe I don't have this package yet

Answer (score 4):

### Simple example using `base::strsplit`

```
x <- c("NYC_23df", "BOS_3_rb", "mgh_3_3_f", "a") 

myCap <- function(x) {
    out <- sapply(x, function(y) {
        temp <- unlist(strsplit(y, "_"))
        out <- temp[1]
        if (length(temp[-1])) {
            out <- paste(temp[1], paste(toupper(temp[-1]), 
                collapse="_"), sep="_") 
        }
        return(out)
    })
    out
}

> myCap(x)
   NYC_23df    BOS_3_rb   mgh_3_3_f           a 
 "NYC_23DF"  "BOS_3_RB" "mgh_3_3_F"         "a"
```

### Example using the [stringr](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package

```
pkg <- "stringr"
if (!require(pkg, character.only=TRUE)) {
    install.packages(pkg)
    require(pkg, character.only=TRUE)   
}

myCap.2 <- function(x) {
    out <- sapply(x, function(y) {
        idx <- str_locate(y, "_")
        if (!all(is.na(idx[1,]))) {
            str_sub(y, idx[,1], nchar(y)) <- toupper(str_sub(y, idx[,1], nchar(y))) 
        }
        return(y)
    })
    out
}

> myCap.2(x)
   NYC_23df    BOS_3_rb   mgh_3_3_f           a 
 "NYC_23DF"  "BOS_3_RB" "mgh_3_3_F"         "a"
```